# smarty error message

Tags: smarty

I get this message when running the code:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _GET in
>   /homepages/40/d35550088/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/e67335bdbe5116dd4daf1e08d56ae4cdd2230780.file.edit.tpl.cache.php
>   on line 99

Line 99 of the compiled template:
`<b><?php echo $_GET['Table'];?>`

I work with Get: 
`{$smarty.get.Table}`

Is it better to use the php REQUEST and then assign a variable to smarty ?

It might be more efficient to use the smarty construct to fetch a url variable ?
How to solve the undefined variable problem ?

Regarding error-reporting, I use the default value.
Regarding ini, I use: ini_set('display_errors', 0);
So no notices should appear , it is strange !

Comment: Sending unvalidated GET directly to the output practically _asks_ for (not saying "enables", but you're close) injection attacks.

Comment: Note this is a `notice`, not an `error`. Notice basically means "code smell and a potential bug; just saying".

Comment: An `undefined` notice will appear anytime `Table` is not present in GET. I would be surprised if `$_GET` didn't exist, but not much - I don't have high hopes on PHP.

Comment: I check the get variables in php `if in_array( $_REQUEST['table'], array with tables)... else die()`. So if there might be an injection, php will die and smarty will not be called. Is this realistic ?